# How to block/unlock USB port in mac os x programatically without reboot

Tags: macos

Is there any way to block/unblock USB mass storage device in MacOS X  using `script` or `I/O framework` without reboot ?

The same can be done in Window easily using system commands, so I wanted to know if this is possible on OS X.

Comment: Might be related to this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59764/how-to-disable-individual-usb-ports-by-script

Comment: You can disable all them at once: http://www.techkaki.com/2009/08/how-to-enable-disable-usb-ports-storage-device-access-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: in this case system need to be reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apple's Workgroup Manager to [to configure removable media access without a server](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4181).  After you've disabled removable media access via Workgroup Manager, you can use the Export menu command to save the policy file that implements those restrictions.  Then you can script enabling/disabling those restrictions using `dscl . -mcximport` (you can read more about it in [Enterprise Mac Managed Preferences](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430229373)).

Answer (score 1):

You can set an external disk policy using either local mcx or a configuration profile. This way when a mass storage device is connected to USB/FireWire/Thunderbolt you can tell it not to mount or to mount read-only.

Another solution with a lot more moving pieces would be to create a launchd job that only allows particular deviceIDs to connect via an [xpc stream handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/xpc_set_event_stream_handler.3.html).